# PHP session variable alter mid runtime

Tags: php, mysql

I've got this fragment of PHP code - the aim is to connect to a MySQL database, return all value of 'title' then return all values of 'date_time' for that title. However, I'm having trouble being able to set a session variable which the date_time can then call upon to find the relevant data.

This is the code I have:

```
<p>
<form action="ShowSelect.php" method="post">
<SELECT NAME="title" onchange = "$_SESSION['title']=title">
<option value="--"> Please Select a show</option>
<?php

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pwd);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql= "SELECT title FROM production"; 
    $handle = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $handle->execute();
    $res = $handle->fetchAll();

        foreach($res as $row) {
        echo '<option>'. $row['title'] .'</option>';
        }




  ?>
  </SELECT>
  </form>

<form action="ShowSelect.php" method="post">
<select NAME="date_time">
<option value="--"> Please Select a time</option>
<?php
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pwd);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT date_time FROM performance WHERE title='{$_SESSION['title']}'"; 
        $handle = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $handle->execute();
        $res = $handle->fetchAll();


            foreach($res as $row) {
            echo '<option>'. $row['date_time'] .'</option>';
        }       
        $_SESSION['date'] = 'date_time';

?>
</select>
</form>
</p>
```

The issues I have is updating the second database call 'on the fly' as it were. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to set a server session variable from client/browser code.  This is not how PHP/HTML work.  What is it you think this is doing?  `<SELECT NAME="title" onchange = "$_SESSION['title']=title">`

Comment: Yeah I figured that probably isn't doing anything (I've altered it so it's actually PHP now) - what I want it to do is when you select an option from the dropdown menu, it sets the value of 'title' as the session variable $_SESSION['title'] so that the date_time drop down can reference that value and call the relevant data.

Comment: @Madbreaks don't know if you saw this?